How to download a csv file programmatically
I have a URL to a CSV file. The size of the file is 300kb with 2700 rows and 15 columns.
I have tried multiple things in Python and C# but ending with the exception

Remote end closed connection without response**

Things which I have tried
Python:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

# Download CSV with read_csv
df = pd.read_csv('https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full_17072024.csv', low_memory=False)

And again in Python
import urllib.request

url = 'https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full_17072024.csv'
filename = 'large_file.csv'

def download_large_file(url, filename):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(filename, 'wb') as out_file:
        while True:
            chunk = response.read(8192)  # Download in 8KB chunks
            if not chunk:
                break
            out_file.write(chunk)

download_large_file(url, filename)
print("File downloaded successfully!")

C#
using System.Net;

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile("URL");


(As an aside, 300KB is really not "a very huge file". Based on the title, I'd expected it to be in the multi-gigabytes, potentially with a problem of trying to download it all into memory first.)

If I needed to transfer files, my first thought is to use FTP (and C#). And 300K isn't big; and zipped it will probably come in at (only) 30K.

If all 3 client approaches are failing: this suggests the server is a problem - we can't diagnose the server from here.

Does it download from a browser? curl?

Unable to download NSE data using python

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78812086/issues-running-python-script-as-azure-function?noredirect=1#comment138958272_78812086 Can i know what happened to this thread @NutsAndBolts?

The problem is that server need some previous cookie should be in the request to serve you with the file here is a complete program in c# will give you that functionality
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
 
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
    UseCookies = true,
};

HttpClient client = new(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/csv"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new("gzip"));


// first vist the Main Page to obtain required cookies
Console.Write("vist Main Page to obtain cookies...");
var MainPage = new Uri(@"https://www.nseindia.com");
var mainPageRes = await client.GetAsync(MainPage);

if (!mainPageRes.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed!");
    Console.WriteLine("can't obtains cookies form the main page");
    Console.WriteLine("status code: " + mainPageRes.StatusCode);
    return;
}
Console.WriteLine("done.");

Console.Write("start to download csv file ....");
var csvUri = new Uri(@"https://nsearchives.nseindia.com/products/content/sec_bhavdata_full_17072024.csv");
var response = await client.GetAsync(csvUri);

if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Faile.");
    Console.WriteLine("Can't download the file");
    Console.WriteLine("status code: " + response.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers);
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine("done.");

var filename = "sec_bhavdata_full_17072024.csv";
using var contentStreem = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
using var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

Console.Write("start to save content to file....");
await contentStreem.CopyToAsync(stream);
Console.WriteLine("done");
try
{
    if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
    {
        Process.Start("explorer.exe", ".");
    }
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine($"file name is {filename}");
}


Thanks your code worked. How you found out that it needs cookies? If I just paste the URL of csv in incognito, I get the file.

I have used postman and rest client to found that link make a some redirection and set some cookies in this process, so your browser will automatically follow that redirection and preserve the cookies ....... but in C# Htttpclient The Authorization header is cleared on auto-redirects so we first obtained that cookie from the main page and then request the resources
